# Rails html.erb Select input convert to Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, slim-lang

I am trying to convert all my html.erb files into .slim in my new project. I am missing last one inside of my form - a select input.

The form.html.erb looks

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :document_id, value: @doc.id %>

   <%= f.label :Obor %>
   <%= select(:user, :job, [
       ["Choose work"],
       ["Admin"],
       ["Other"]
       ],  {disabled: "Choose work", selected: "Choose work"}, class: "form") %>

    <%= f.button "Submit" %>
<% end%>
```

Everything works just in the way I want. I tried to make it in a .slim in this way:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
   = f.hidden_field :document_id, value: @doc.id

   = f.label :Obor
   = select(:user, :job, [
       ["Choose work"],
       ["Admin"],
       ["Other"]
       ],  {disabled: "Choose work", selected: "Choose work"}, class: "form")

    = f.button "Submit"
```

It does not work with an error: **Unknown line indicator** ->

```
new.slim, Line xx, Column xx
    ["Choose work"]
```

How I can convert the select from html.erb into .slim? Thank you.

**EDIT - ANSWER:** Thanks to erb_to_slim gem that Ricardo mentioned I figured out the solution. I simply missed the rails indicator on each row of the selector. The answer is:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
   = f.hidden_field :document_id, value: @doc.id

   = f.label :Obor
   = select(:user, :job, [
       = ["Choose work"],
       = ["Admin"],
       = ["Other"]
       = ],  {disabled: "Choose work", selected: "Choose work"}, class: "form")

    = f.button "Submit"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you tryed to use the gem erb_to_slim?

In your terminal type:

```
gem install erb_to_slim
```

And inside your project folder, use:

```
erb_to_slim
```

All erb files will be converted to slim and the erb files will be renamed.

Maybe this can help.

Comment: I was looking for the syntax but thanks to your answer I converted it and found what was wrong. I missed "= " in every selection. Thank you!